# How to get correct inference in typed [value, error] tuple in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to type a tuple [value | null, Error | null] and get correct type inference?

Currently i'm using this, but i dont get the correct type inference

```
type TypedTuple<T = any> = [T, null] | [null, Error]

const fn = <T>(data: T): TypedTuple<T> => {
    try {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) throw new Error('error')
        return [data, null]
    }catch(error){
        return [null, error]
    }
}

const [data, error] = fn('test')

if(error){
    console.error(data) // data should be infered to null, but get infered as string | null
}
```

Comment: The question is confusing about the ask: `[value | null, Error | null]` is different than `[T, null] | [null, Error]`. Perhaps the entire content of `fn` is not even relevant when the focus is refined.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the destructuring of the result, as once you have destructured those values into two separate variables, typescript considers their types separately.

To fix this, do your narrowing logic *before* destructuring your items. That way, the narrowing check takes place on the original type: `[T, null] | [null, Error]`. This way typescript can correctly trace the relationship between the two values.

So something like:

```
const testResult = fn('test')

if(testResult[1]) {
    const m = testResult[0] // Inferred as null.
    console.error(m)
}
```

The key takeaway is that if you destructure before the check, you break the relationship between the two values. Since TypeScript doesn't know which kind of tuple it is at that time, it will give each variable the union of types for it's corresponding index. So `data` is given the type `null | T` and the `error` gets `Error | null`. Since each variable has it's own distinct type now, narrowing one will have no effect on the other.

However, if you can help typescript identify which of the two tuple types your result is before breaking them apart, you will receive the correct inference.